# What is the real current status of Twisted on Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, twisted

Had used some [twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki) using Python 2.6 few years back, and since then stopped using Python. Recently starting picking up on Python 3, and was checking status of twisted support for Python 3 which was very thin back when I left.

**Introduction** section of the [Latest document](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/python3.html) on the topic says this:

> Twisted is currently being ported to work with Python 3.4+. This
>   document covers Twisted-specific issues in porting your code to Python
>   3.
>
> Most, but not all, of Twisted has been ported, and therefore only a
>   subset of modules are installed under Python 3. You can see the
>   remaining modules that need to be ported at
>   [twisted.python._setup.notPortedModules](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/18.7.0/api/twisted.python._setup.notPortedModules.html), if it is not listed there,
>   then most of all of that module will be ported.

And clicking on the **twisted.python._setup.notPortedModules** shows no module listed.

Does that mean that twisted is now fully supported on Python 3 ? Or just the list is incorrect ? If so, are the samples / examples converted for Python 3 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most likely definitive resource on this topic is the continuous integration system.

According to https://travis-ci.org/twisted/twisted, a recent run had 9957 passing tests on Python 3.6 compared to 9933 passing tests on Python 2.7.  There is some slop in these numbers because the test suite includes some tests which are only relevant to Python 2.x and others which are only relevant to Python 3.x (therefore we would not expect exactly the same number of tests to run on each runtime) however these numbers are so close that I would say that Twisted has basically been complete ported to Python 3.6.  Problems that remain are probably more likely to be "regular bugs" rather than unported code.

Comment: Regarding the content of [twisted/python/_setup.py](https://github.com/twisted/twisted/blob/eb2aaeb5d8e95ad1c4ec1889855d9cd151f696e2/src/twisted/python/_setup.py#L382) file, a lot of modules are still not ported.

Comment: True.  But they're pretty rarely used modules that probably don't affect >99% of users.

Comment: New travis link is here: https://travis-ci.com/github/twisted/twisted